# Content Types not visible under New Button

Tags: 2010, development, content-type, sandbox-solution

I have a Sandboxed Custom Action for SharePoint Designer that can add Content Types to Document Libraries. The problem is that it does not automatically add it under the "New Document". It's not visible, first I thought for some reasons the ContentType.Hidden was "true", but setting it to false from code did not make any different either.

From the webs people are talking about the RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder, but that is not available in sandboxed solutions.

Anyone know how I can mange to make it Visible pr default from code(C#)?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same problem as you...

Comment: I'm facing the same problem...

Comment: I'm afraid I never found the answer, and haven't looked at the issue since. Let's hope someone comes around and have an answer.